# ValueTuple error with VB.Net

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm using VB.Net, .Net 4.6.1, VS 2015 Update 3, and installed nuget package `System.ValueTuple 4.3.1`

Unless I'm missing something, the value tuple syntax causes an error:
[image]

Comment: take a look here http://www.obelink.com/index.php/2017/03/19/visual-studio-2017use-valuetuples-visual-basic-net/

Comment: That syntax is not supported until VS2017.  Even if you install the NuGet package, the 2015 compiler doesn't understand the syntax.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway I'm using VS2015 and it support that sintax.